# Reference lost but still not in a undefined state?

Tags: c#, events, reference

I was working with the WebBrowser and tried something, but it's a more general understanding thing. I will just show what I was doing as an example.

Code from the main method:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
     WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
     browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebDocumentCompleted);
     browser.Navigate(URL);
   }
  }
```

event handler method:

```
void WebDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{..}
```

Why does this work? Aren't the references to the WebBrowser lost in the scope of the main method and theoreticially the GC could collect? Which would mean this is an undefined state? 
I know that there are no undefined states in C#.

Comment: I assume dmr is asking why the event still gets raised. The duplicated question doesn't answer this. The real answer is that WebBrowser keeps itself alive while a document is loading.

Comment: The accepted answer might not be the best possible answer. However, the question is a duplicate anyway (imho).

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why the event still gets raised, but also I seem to have a misunderstanding of the GC. However the link of Tim helps me as well.